# How do I prevent the startup command on an Azure Linux App Service being overwritten on publish?

Tags: azure, .net-core

I have an .net core application hosted on an Azure App service running linux. After running into issues with libgdiplus not being found, I ran across the solution to use `apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils libgdiplus libc6-dev && dotnet YourWebSite.dll` as the startup command in Azure. Unfortunately whenever I push code, the command is overwritten with the default `dotnet YourWebSite.dll`. I've looked through the publish settings in Visual Studio, but I can't find anything that seems to relate to the startup command.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can change the start up command from Visual Studio. But you can change the start up command in Azure portal instead.

Go to your app service, go to Configurations

[image]

Here you can change the start up command.

Comment: The title says that the Startup command gets overwritten on publish, therefore it doesn't answer his question.